# Help: delete-other-windows only working from the original window

Tags: window, window-splitting, project

## Overview

I'm having trouble understanding from [my current config](https://github.com/ldeck/nix-home/blob/a9a758c242dc151d2969504366caa5cff8edd590/lib/defaults/emacs.nix) why `C-x 1` (i.e., `M-x delete-other-windows`) *does not work* when executed from a window in a project that was created as a result of either `C-x 2` (i.e., `M-x split-window-below`) or `C-x 3` (i.e., `M-x split-window-right`).

It *does work* as expected when either running vanilla emacs (`emacs -Q -nw`) or when not having navigated to files via `project.el`. So there's clearly a package that's introduced a change in behaviour for this in preventing `delete-other-windows` from doing just that.

Is it `winner-mode` or `treemacs` or `lsp` or something else?

**How do I trace where a no-op is occurring?**

## Investigations

1. I start emacs
2. Run the command `find-file` via `C-x C-f` to open a file
3. Run the command `split-window-below` via `C-x 2`
4. Run the command `other-window` via `C-x o` to switch focus to the new window
5. Run the command `find-file` via `C-x C-f` to open another file
6. Run the command `delete-other-windows` via `C-x 1` to collapse all other windows and maximise the current one
7. This should leave the the currently focused window and the other file as the only one visible

This works.

If I replace steps 2 and 5 by running the command `project-find-file` via `C-x p f` (after having switched to a file in a project... e.g., via `C-x p p f`) this also works.

If I enable `treemacs` and open files from it, it also works.

If I run a scala spec via lsp-metals, using lsp-any-lens to select the relevant lens, it still works.

## Summary

At some point (which I'm still trying to figure out) while working within a project, the behaviour changes such that `delete-other-windows` stops working if, as stated above, the  window that has focus was created as a split.

So it's a bit baffling and I'm not sure how to reproduce it (yet).

Any pointers on being able to turn on tracing or something when it starts to fail would be great.

Even better, knowing how to force the behaviour would be even better. Thanks!

Comment: Can you bisect your init file to find the culprit package ("there's clearly a package that's...")?

Comment: Yeah @Drew, failing some way to debug it and pinpoint the culprit that may be the only option, but difficult to find time to do :-/

Comment: Bisecting is a binary search: starts out slow, ends up being quick. You can comment parts of your init file (or any files), e.g., 1/2 the file, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,..., using `M-x comment-region`. With a prefix arg it uncomments.